# Error installing jekyll on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

After executing

```
sudo gem install jekyll --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
  jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

but when I check the version of ruby installed I get 2.3.0

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

and when I check the version of ruby in /usr/bin is 1.9.3

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

How do I use the same version of ruby in the whole system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *system* ruby at `1.9.3` and `2.3.0` installed with some version manager.

When you call `sudo ruby` or `sudo gem install` that's using the system Ruby.

If you just use `ruby` or `gem install` that will use the version manager.

In short, just use `gem install jekyll --no-rdoc --no-ri` without the `sudo`.

Comment: When I check the version of jekyll -v. Still doesn't works Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      listen (< 3.1, ~> 3.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems     I followed this steps to install jekyll http://michaelchelen.net/81fa/install-jekyll-2-ubuntu-14-04/